# ASMX webservice with Guid parameter

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, asmx, webmethod

I've got an asmx web service with the following method

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string LoadRegions(Guid id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

When I attempt to call this method, I receive this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: LoadRegions Web Service method 
name is not valid.
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
```

If I change the parameter type from Guid to, say, string, the problem disappears. Suggestions? For testing purposes,  I'm calling the service with this url from Firefox:

```
http://localhost:81/services/ContactService.asmx/LoadRegions
?id=6C388126-5787-4B63-AAFE-5BCC4EA4DF83
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can always change the parameter type to string and do a Guid.Parse.

Comment: @klausbyskov yes, but I'd rather have the framework handle Guid deserialization than have to add what should be unnecessary code to validate the type on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am trying to find formal documentation, but it appears that you cannot use a GUID as an input type on a WebMethod, because it is not something that can be validated on the way in.  But I can't find the exact documentation on it.

I would most likely leave it as a string parameter, and have the first line of your method do a Guid.Parse to validate that it is a GUID, if not, send the user an exception.  This is the way I have seen it done in other implementations that require a GUID on a WebMethod.

Comment: I think this is the way that I'm going to go, though it's annoying to have to go through this extra step for what is, ultimately, a very simple data type. If you find a link explicitly stating that guids aren't supported, please add it to your post.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this using the service with an actual SOAP call?

I don't think http GET is going to allow you to specify *complicated* types.

I'm also pretty sure `6C388126-5787-4B63-AAFE-5BCC4EA4DF83` only represents a GUID to us humans, its a string to a computer - essentially you have a type mismatch and their isn't a method defined with the proper arguments (as far as the OS is concerned).